# Javascript Form Validation (phone)

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I have a form which has name, email and content text area. It all works fine but when I'm trying to add 1 more form input for mobile phone numbers the form wont submit.

**Javascript**:

```
  function hgsubmit() {
    if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.name.value) == false) 
      alert("Please provide your name."); 
    else if (/^\S+@[a-z0-9_.-]+\.[a-z]{2,6}$/i.test(document.hgmailer.email.value) == false)
      alert("A valid email address is required."); 
    else if (/\S+/.test(document.hgmailer.comment.value) == false)
      alert ("Your email content is needed.");
    else { 
      document.hgmailer.submit(); 
      alert ('Thank you!\nYour email is sent.');
    }
  }
```

**HTML**:

```
<form action="http://www.jim123code.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl" method="post"
name="hgmailer"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="info@jim123code.com"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Form E-Mail"> 
  Contact Form
  <br>
  <br> 
  Visitor Name: <input type="text" name="name" size="30" value="">  
  <br> 
  Visitor E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email" size="30" value="">
  <br>
  E-Mail Content: <textarea name="comment" cols="50" rows="5"></textarea>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" value="E-Mail Me!" onclick="hgsubmit();">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.jim123code.com/"> 
</form>
```

The code for the form above is the approved contact form that works with my webhosting provider (ehost). Now i've tried adding a mobile phone number input by copying and pasting the other input types and changing a few things around but no luck. please advise the best way to add a phone number input + the javascript validation code for it to all work together.

Comment: What happens when you add the new input and press the submit button? Are you setting a 'name' property?

Comment: If you want to save the number too, you'll also have to edit `http://www.jim123code.com/cgi-sys/formmail.pl`

Comment: @DiegoLópez no wonder your stackoverflow rating is 753!! my error was not setting the 'name' property, i just had it has name="name", so i took your advice and changed it to name="number" and it worked like a charm!  thanks a lot!

Comment: Sure, is a pleasure to help you, I just created an answer with my suggestion if you could be so kind to accept it I will appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a new input to be sent, be sure to include it inside the form tag and add a unique value for the name property.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="phoneNumber" size="10" value="">
```

For more information about forms check [HTML Forms](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You are gonna have to create a custom formmail script to handle your new form. If you know perl you can try modifying the existing script. Otherwise tough nuggies.